# How to save a ExcelPicture in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, spire.xls

So i have these ExcelPictures that i want to save to a Specfic path.

```
                ExcelPicture picture = sheet.Pictures[minIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

To save the ExcelPicture object to a specific path, you can use:

`picture.Picture.Save(@"ImagePath", ImageFormat.Png);`